# Git push single commit not working

Tags: git, bitbucket, push

I try to push only the commit with ID *9973b14ca19e4571046d8d25bc986ec07199e39c*.

```
git push bbef 9973b14ca19e4571046d8d25bc986ec07199e39c:refs/heads/feature/25062018_offline-seite_ef
```

I logged in to Bitbucket to create the pull request, but I noticed, that there are multiple commits, even though this is a new remote branch.

So I deleted the remote branch in bitbucket and pushed it again, same result...

[image]

Why does it not work and how can I push only the single commit instead of multiple ones? Why does it happen?

Comment: You should share the output of your command, i.e. the error message, so people can understand what went wrong.

Comment: Are you very new to Git?  You typically don't push _commits_ to Git, you push an entire branch, with that branch's entire history; this is true at least from a conceptual point of view.  Try to tell us more about what went wrong, because I don't see an obvious problem here.

Comment: try `git push bbef HEAD:refs/heads/feature/25062018_offline-seite_ef`  , git will smartly push all committed changes to remote

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, the problem should be obvious though. I pushed a single commit which only changed 4 files, but 12 commits where pushed together with it.

Comment: You pushed a _branch_ which also happen to have those 12 _commits_.  If this isn't the result you want, then your branch/flow/logic is off.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, What!? I pushed a single commit to a remote branch as you can see..

Comment: @prudviraj, I don't want to commit HEAD I want to commit only the changes from that specific commit, which is in the green rectangle in the screenshot.

Comment: got it , @Black , try  cherrypick in that case ,ref : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Answer (score 2):

When you run `git push`, you have your Git offer to the other Git:

- a specific commit (by hash ID or name), *plus*
- the entire history of commits leading *to* that specific commit.

(The other Git will tell your Git when to stop offering previous commits because the other Git has them already.)  This is precisely what you are seeing.

It will help to stop, back up, and *draw the commit graph* (or at least part of it).  You can run `git log --graph`—I generally prefer the "help from A DOG" variant, `git log --all --decorate --online --graph`, **A**ll **D**ecorate **O**neline **G**raph = A D O G—to have Git draw the graph rather crudely for you.  Some GUIs draw the graph their own way.

Remember that in Git, a *branch name* is simply a human-readable name for one (1) hash ID.  Each commit has a unique hash ID assigned at the time the commit is made, but each commit also contains the hash ID of its *parent* commits—usually just one, or two for merge commits—and these string the commits together into chains that branch and, at merge commits, merge back together.  It does not matter whether you draw the graph vertically, with newer commits at the top, as Git does, or horizontally, with newer commits at the right, as usually I do in StackOverflow postings.  What matters is actually *drawing the graph*, because once you have done that, what Git is doing becomes obvious:

```
A  <-B  <-C   <--master
```

This represents the total sum of commits in a tiny three-commit repository.  Each uppercase letter stands in for the actual hash ID.  The branch *name*, `master`, remembers the actual hash ID of the *last* commit, commit `C`.  Commit `C` itself remembers the hash ID of its previous or *parent* commit `B`.  `B` remembers the hash ID of `A`, and since `A` is the very first commit, it has no parent.

Whenever Git needs to, it starts at whatever commit you tell it—or your current commit by default—and then *works backwards* through this graph.  If you have your Git push one particular commit to some other Git, your Git must push that commit *and* every parent up to the point where your commits match their commits.  So suppose you have, for instance:

```
...--*--*------o--o---o--X--o--o   <-- branch
         \           /
          o--o------o
```

where `*` represents a commit that the server already has—you pushed those already, or you got them from the server, for instance—and `o` represents a commit you have that they don't.  At this point, if you push the third commit (towards the right) along the bottom row, they will receive three commits: all three from the bottom row.  That's because starting from that commit and working backwards, it takes three commits to make your new one join up with their existing ones.  If you push one of the two top row commits just after the `*`, your Git will send one or two commits.  If you push a commit that comes after the merge, your Git will push at least *six* commits.  Pushing commit `X` here pushes seven: `X` itself, and the required preceding six.

If you want to push a single commit that adds on to the second starred commit, you must first *make* a single commit that adds on to the second starred commit:

```
          Y   <-- new-name
         /
...--*--*------o--o---o--X--o--o   <-- branch
         \           /
          o--o------o
```

Once you have this setup, if you push commit `Y`, they already have the starred commits (of course) so your Git will in fact push a single commit, namely commit `Y`.

#### How to *make* this single commit

In order to *create* commit `Y`, first you need<sup>1</sup> to create a new branch name pointing to the final commit `*`.  Find its hash ID, or any other name that uniquely identifies it, and check out that particular commit and create a name for it:

```
git checkout -b new-name <hash-id>
```

This leaves the graph itself unchanged but makes the new name pointing to that commit.<sup>2</sup>  The `git checkout -b` command puts you on this new branch at the same time as creating the name.  (Note that at this point, pushing the new branch to the server would send the server *no* commits, and merely create the name on the server as well.)

```
        /----------------------------- new-name (HEAD)
        |
        v
...--*--*------o--o---o--X--o--o   <-- branch
         \           /
          o--o------o
```

Now you can run:

```
git cherry-pick <hash-of-desired-commit-X>
```

which in this case is:

```
git cherry-pick 9973b14ca19e4571046d8d25bc986ec07199e39c
```

This has Git examine commit `9973b14ca19e4571046d8d25bc986ec07199e39c`.  Git will extract its parent commit's snapshot, and this commit's snapshot, and diff them (a la `git diff`).<sup>3</sup>  Git will then apply whatever these changes are to the current commit, to make a new commit that is a *copy* of `X`:

```
          Y  <-- new-name (HEAD)
         /
...--*--*------o--o---o--X--o--o   <-- branch
         \           /
          o--o------o
```

and *now* you have what you need: a commit that can be pushed by itself, because `Y`'s history—its parent and grandparent and so on—*already exists on the server*.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, you can do this without a *name*, using "detached HEAD" mode.  I'd advise against that, at this point.

<sup>2</sup>You can also create the branch name using `git branch`:

```
git branch new-name <hash-id>
```

You then have to run `git checkout new-name` to get *on* that branch, i.e., to attach your `HEAD` to that name.

<sup>3</sup>Technically, cherry-pick is actually a merge operation that results in a non-merge commit: merge-as-a-verb, *to merge*, but not as an adjective or noun.  This lets the cherry-pick work in a situation in which a simple patch would not.  However, this particular complication is mostly irrelevant here: it only matters if the cherry-pick results in a merge conflict.

Answer (score -1):

You think you pushed only one commit but acctually you pushed a lot of commits instead. The commit 9973b14 commit depends on other commits that don't exist in the feature/25062018_offline-seite_ef branch so they will be pushed together. This is the way Git works.

You need to create a local branch based on the remote feature/25062018_offline-seite_ef branch then cherrypick the 9973b14 commit and then push to remote.

Comment: How exactly can I cherry pick that commit? I read the following documentation, but there are no examples. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick.

Comment: I tried `git cherry-pick 9973b14ca19e4571046d8d25bc986ec07199e39c` but the staging area stays empty.